# Is it reasonable to use a generator as iterable in Pool.map

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Pool.map requires a callable as its first parameter and an iterable as its second parameter (see [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)).

It will split up the iterable in chunks and pass them to the workers in the pool.

Is that possible if the iterable itself is a generator? Or does it have to be a sequence (list, np.array etc.)

Comment: Hint: try it and find out ;-) *spoiler alert*: you can.

Comment: You can, but it gets turned into a list anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generator works just fine, but given the work is dispatched eagerly, it must effectively realize the entire generator in one way or another to actually do the work. As it happens, [the implementation of `Pool.map` `list`-ifies any `iterable` without `__len__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L375) before it actually begins dispatching work at all, so passing the generator just means a slight delay before it's forced to realize the generator in memory.

If you want to avoid that, use `imap` or `imap_unordered`, both of which dispatch "live" (though at present even they [dispatch well ahead of the results being returned](https://bugs.python.org/issue19993), so you might end up realizing most of the generator at once, if not all).